# Focus on an element when IOS VoiceOver is on (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ios, accessibility

I've been wrapping my heads around IOS's VoiceOver feature. I have a *Skip to Main Content* button which should move the focus to the first focusable item in outside of the header.

```
<button id="skip-navigation">Skip to Main Content</button>
```

```
const skipButton = document.getElementById("skip-navigation")

skipButton.onclick = () => { 
  const firstFocusable = getFirstFocusable()

  if (firstFocusable) {
    firstFocusable.focus() // this works with other screen readers (eg. Talkback, MS Narrator, etc.)
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: `getFirstFocusable` is a custom function that grabs the first element that's a descendant of `main` that is considered *focusable* and it is returning an element.

```
const getFocusable = parent => parent.querySelectorAll('button, a[href], input, select, textarea, [tabindex]:not([tabindex="-1"])')[0]
```

I haven't found a way to do this as results keep on showing how to do it in Objective C or Swift.

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `getFirstFocusable()`, some custom function (if so could you share it) or have you got confused with seeing loads of Swift code?

Comment: nevermind it is react, do you want a react answer or a vanilla JS answer?

Comment: `getFirstFocusable` is just a custom code that grabs an element that's considered focusable that lives as a descendant of `main`. Either one is fine.

Comment: without sharing that we can't see if you are implementing it correctly, could you share that please bud as that is likely to be the cause of your issue. The only thing I can see is that `getFirstFocusable` is returning `null` or `false` for some reason so the focus is never getting called, have you tried the age old `alert("here")` within the `if(firstFocusable)` to check it actually gets there so you can test without having to link your phone up for console?

Comment: Don't worry, I did check those. I added the code for the function and it does return an element that can be focused.

Comment: yeah sorry I always start at the obvious and work from there. If you two finger swipe down does it read from the top of the document or the focused location? Are you double tapping to activate the button? (yet again sorry if stating obvious stuff, if you are a strong user of VoiceOver then tell me to skip this bit!)